# Volume decreasing

Tags: volume

When I wake up my phone started to decrease volume. If I do something about notification(like taking sms, phone calling) it decrease ringer+notifications and I can't change by the way there is no problem media+apps volume. But like notification if I do something about media this time there is no problem with ringer+notification but media+apps decreasing, it's unstoppable. Volume bar always top of my screen and  cuz of that I can't use my return button I should close window with holding. What should I do?

Comment: What phone do you have? Is the volume button stuck or something?

Comment: I have HTC 8X and volume button isn't stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The **media+apps** volume control disappeared for me too. This is what I did to get it back:

1. Restart phone

*After I did this the volume control for **media+apps** was back.*